# How to apply a renderer only to a particular cell instead of whole column in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer, border

I am quiet new to Swing. I have a JTable in which images are displayed in each cell. I need to create a RED border only around the cell which is currently selected. To do this I used following renderer class:

```
public class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
 JLabel lbl=new JLabel();     

 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column )
 {

     lbl.setIcon((ImageIcon)value); 
     if(isSelected && hasFocus)
     {
         lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.RED, Color.yellow));
     }
     return lbl;


 }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I click on any cell in the JTable then instead of that particular cell the border is displayed for all the cells of the given column. I only need the border around the selected cell and not around all the cells present in that particular column.

Comment: *"it is quiet urgent"*  1) The word you are after is 'quite'.  Quiet means 'silent', or 'no sound'.  2) It is best not to mention your timetable.  It will not make people answer faster, but might get you ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Andrew. I'll take a note of this.

Comment: You can edit your own question at any time.  If you do so (and let me know), I can remove my 1st comment as 'noise'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try to unset the border if the cell is not selected?

```
     if(isSelected && hasFocus)
     {
         lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.RED, Color.yellow));
     }else{
         lbl.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder() );
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I was missing the else condition you mentioned above. Now its working fine.... :)